# Scope of SVG file

Tags: inkscape

I have numerous objects in my SVG file, but I only want to use one object for import into Android Studio. How shall I edit/save the SVG file, so that only that object is imported as SVG in Android Studio? I don't want to delete the other objects from the SVG file.

Comment: What is wrong with copying this single object and pasting it into a new SVG file?

Comment: @juancho I want to keep all my sources in one file, to facilitate editing and recombining objects.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio apparently only imports that part of the file that is within the Inkscape page borders. So you can select an object and then select "Resize Page to drawing or selection". Only that object will be imported into Android Studio.